# Alternatives to saying beginning to end

Tags: word-choice, american-english, sentence-choice

I can say a sentence: **I built this product from beginning to end**. The intention is 
to communicate that I alone worked on this product (Software product) and no one else. And I started from nothing and built it. 
 Is there a better way to communicate this? May be a single word for the three words **beginning to end**

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***[from scratch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from_scratch)***:

> (idiomatic) From the beginning; starting with no advantage or prior preparation.

Comment: Is this an Idiom? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from-scratch This doesn't mention this as an idiom. Just some extra doubts